# How to pre-define links in Jekyll _config.yml using Kramdown links_def options?

Tags: configuration, jekyll, kramdown

https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/markdown/ says that link definitions for Jekyll can be pre-defined using Kramdown's `link_defs` options, but I'm unable to make it work.

https://kramdown.gettalong.org/options.html says that the value of `link_defs` must be a Hash with the link identifier as key and a two-part array of values (URL and title). Here's the relevant portion of my `_config.yml`:

```
kramdown:
  link_defs:
    check:
      - first
      - second
  syntax_highlighter_opts:
    disable: true
```

And here's the error I get running `bundle exec jekyll build`:

```
jekyll 3.9.0 | Error:  undefined method `gsub' for :check:Symbol
```

Changing the link ID from `check` to anything else doesn't make a difference; using an inline array `['first', 'second']` doesn't help either.

Comment: It seems that Jekyll is converting the "check" string into a :check symbol. Could you try 'link_defs: "{check: [first, second]}"`?

Answer (score 1):

The solution from @gettalong works and can be combined with YAML's folded multiline strings:

```
kramdown:
  link_defs: >
    {
      check: [first, second],
      another: [third, "fourth"]
    }
```

It isn't pretty, but it works...

Comment: However, `site.kramdown.link_defs` is a string, not a Hash, when you process it in Jekyll, so you can't (for example) loop over it to build a table of external links for reference. See https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/8588 for the bug report.